# Shell - Run additional command on failure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, pdf2swf

I have this script that I am currently running that works great for all instances but one:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 pdfopt test.pdf test.opt.pdf &>/dev/null
 pdf2swf test.opt.pdf test.swf
 [ "$?" -ne 0 ] && exit 2
```

More lines to execute follow the above code ...

How would I go about changing this script to run "`pdf2swf test.pdf test.swf`" if "`pdf2swf test.opt.pdf test.swf`" fails?  If the second attempt fails, then I would "`exit 2`".

Thanks

Comment: This is racey, `pdfopt` might not finish before `pdf2swf` runs. Let the prior block until finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/path/to/pdfopt test.pdf test.opt.pdf >/dev/null && {

    pdf2swf test.opt.pdf test.swf
    ... maybe do more stuff here, in the future ...
    exit_here_nicely
} 

code_that_is_reached_if_pdfopt_failed
```

In your example:

```
pdfopt test.pdf test.opt.pdf &>/dev/null
```

... `pdfopt` runs in the background, you have no idea how long it may take to complete. Let it block, so the code in the parens is reached only if it worked.

A function wrapping that could easily launch in the background, but each process blocks until the first command exits as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Short circuiting "OR" should do what you want:

```
pdf2swf test.opt.pdf test.swf || pdf2swf test.pdf test.swf
```

Comment: `pdf2swf test.opt.pdf test.swf || pdf2swf test.pdf test.swf || exit 2`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want a Makefile instead of a shell script. A makefile aborts automatically it one of the commands fail. Alternatively, you can add `[ "$?" -ne 0 ] && exit 2` after every command

Comment: That won't work without explicit dependencies for both targets, and is questionable with `make -jxx` if they lack. Even if done correctly, its still a shell script, just wrapped up in a Makefile :)

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for do this OR do this to consider it a success?  So this doesn't help.  Also, if you want your shell script to exit if any of the commands returns non-zero use "#!/bin/sh -e" instead of using a makefile or writing 'exit 2' after every line.